# Traversing from this.el to parentEl returns undefined, but the reverse returns the element

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to establish a reference from a child to a component in it's parent element.  I would expect to be able to reference it by calling `this.el.parentEl.components['parent']` in the init() function, but this returns undefined.

Other test cases work fine:
1. Referencing the child component from the parent works fine from within the parent component.
2. Referencing the parent component from a code snippet below the html.
3. Referencing the parent component from the child element from a code snippet below the html.

Is this an issue of life cycle?  Why is there a difference between child and parent in this case?

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>

<script>

  AFRAME.registerComponent('parent', {

    multiple: false,

    init: function () {
      this.child = this.el.children[0].components['child']
      console.log("child component: ", this.child); //This works
    }        
  })


  AFRAME.registerComponent('child', {

    multiple: false,

    init: function () {
      this.parent = this.el.parentEl.components['parent']
      console.log("parent component: ", this.parent); //Undefined
    }        
  })

</script>
```

```
<a-scene>

  <a-entity parent>
    <a-entity child></a-entity>
  </a-entity>

</a-scene>


<script>

  var parent = document.querySelector('[parent]').components.parent
  console.log("parent component from below: ", parent); //This works

  var parentfromchild = document.querySelector('[child]').parentEl.components['parent']
  console.log("parent from child from below: ", parentfromchild); //This works

</script>
```

Comment: I recommend using Glitch to provide an executable example that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 2):

When `init` is called the parent has not yet initialized. The scene loads from children to parent. Wait for the scene to load by listening to the `loaded` event: [How to detect when a scene is loaded in A-Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727501/how-to-detect-when-a-scene-is-loaded-in-a-frame)